# Serial number doesn't reset in reports when printed next time (designed by openoffice)

Tags: odoo

I am using openoffice for designing reports. There i specify "1." in serial number column. And the whole record is in repeat, so the serial number correctly gets printed as 1,2,3 etc. But when printing the report again the serial number is 4,5,6 and not 1,2,3. which means the serial number is not reset. How do i reset it or is there any other way to print serial number in reports while designing from openoffice. Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0):

use sequence function of reportlab to do sequencing instead of manual sequencing.